# How To Create CycleTile in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Apps

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

CycleTileData is Used in WP8.0 When coming to WP8.1 CycleTileData is not existing what is the alternative CycleTileData in WP8.1 Universal Apps(Runtime Apps)

```
CycleTileData cycleTile = new CycleTileData();
cycleTile.Title =ResourceHelper.ProjectName;
cycleTile.Count=AppSettings.LiveTileHistroryCount;
cycleTile.SmallBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/logo159x159.png", UriKind.Relative);
cycleTile.CycleImages = cycleimagelist;
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a full list of Live Tile Templates [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx) for Windows Phone 8.1 RT. You can use something like "TileSquareImage" and "TileWideImage". You can get these Live Tiles to cycle up to five images. It was nine previously on the CycleTileData Template. Also, there is no more 'Ken Burns' effect unfortunately.

The new Live Tile templates do add some more flexibility like being able to add information on the reverse flip side of each image e.g. "TileSquarePeekImageAndText04".